# Refused to frame Keycloak URL because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'"

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, token, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am trying to hit the Keycloak server on a load of the page so users can authenticate there and obtain the token. When I provide all the information to my Keycloak I am getting the error:

```
Refused to frame Keycloak URL because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".
```

Following is the code I am using my Nuxt 3 or Vuejs 3 application:

composables/fetchToken.js:

```
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js';
const config = useRuntimeConfig();

export default async function fetchToken() {
  console.log("WITHIN FETCH");

  const initOptions = useState("initOptions", () => ({
    realm: config.public.KEYCLOAK_REALM_NAME,
    clientId: config.public.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID, 
    url: config.public.KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL
  }));

  console.log(JSON.stringify(initOptions.value,null,4))

  // Create a new instance of the Keycloak constructor
  const keycloak = new Keycloak(initOptions.value);

  console.log(keycloak)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(keycloak,null,4))

  try {
    // Initialize Keycloak and handle the authentication
    const auth = await keycloak.init({ onLoad: 'login-required' });
    
    console.log('Token:', keycloak.token);

    if (!auth) {
      window.location.reload();
    } else {
      console.log('Authenticated');
    }

    if (keycloak.token) {
      window.localStorage.setItem('keycloakToken', keycloak.token);
    }

    //redirect to the home page after login
    await router.push('/');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error initializing Keycloak:', error);
  }
}
```

And I am using this in my following page:
pages/index.vue:

```
<template>
</template>
  
<script setup>
//Execute the onBeforeMount to redirect to Keycloak Login
onBeforeMount(() => {
  fetchToken();
});
</script>
```

How to fix the issue in Keycloak and get the authentication and token on reload of the page?

Comment: Same issue and sadly I never figured that one out.

Comment: @ak.leimrey I have added the answer which is working fine for me. I was able to fetch the token and use it for various requests.

Answer (score 1):

Providing the answer as it can be useful to someone in the future. I used the Vue 3 application to fetch the token from keycloak using the keycloak js and also logout the user from the keycloak.

I believe using the following is important, if not then check your keycloak configuration in Keycloak UI.

```
    // Initialize Keycloak and handle the authentication
    const auth = await keycloak.init({
      onLoad: "login-required",
      flow: "implicit",
    });
```

I used the following approach to fetch the token from my keycloak using the keycloak js:

my env file:

```
KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL=http://localhost:9080
KEYCLOAK_LOGOUT_URL=http://localhost:9080/realms/myRealmName/protocol/openid-connect/logout
API_SERVER_URL=http://localhost:8080/
```

Following is my composable file to fetch the token and store it:

```
import Keycloak from "keycloak-js";
const config = useRuntimeConfig();

const initOptions = useState("initOptions", () => ({
  realm: config.public.KEYCLOAK_REALM_NAME,
  clientId: config.public.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
  url: config.public.KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL,
}));

// Create a new instance of the Keycloak constructor
const keycloak = new Keycloak(initOptions.value);

//Function to login to Keycloak and generate token and ID token
export async function keycloakLogin() {
  try {
    // Initialize Keycloak and handle the authentication
    const auth = await keycloak.init({
      onLoad: "login-required",
      flow: "implicit",
    });

    //If not authenticated then reload to show login page
    if (!auth) {
      window.location.reload();
    }

    //If token is present then store it in localstorage
    if (keycloak.token) {
      console.log(keycloak.token);
      console.log(keycloak.idToken);
      window.localStorage.setItem("keycloakToken", keycloak.token);
      window.localStorage.setItem("idToken", keycloak.idToken);
    }

    // Call the setupTokenChecking function to initiate token checking
    setupTokenChecking();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error initializing Keycloak:", error);
  }
}

//Function to logout the user if the user has clicked logout button
export async function keycloakLogout() {
  const logoutURL =
    config.public.KEYCLOAK_LOGOUT_URL +
    "?id_token_hint=" +
    localStorage.getItem("idToken") +
    "&post_logout_redirect_uri=" +
    encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);

  keycloak
    .logout({ redirectUri: logoutURL })
    .then((success) => {
      console.log("User logout success ", success);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("User logout error ", error);
    });
}

// Call the checkAndRenewToken function initially and set up periodic checks
async function setupTokenChecking() {
  await checkAndRenewToken(); // Check the token immediately upon setup
  const tokenCheckInterval = 5 * 60 * 1000; // periodic token checks for 5 minutes in milliseconds
  setInterval(checkAndRenewToken, tokenCheckInterval);
}

// Function to periodically check and renew the Keycloak token
export async function checkAndRenewToken() {
  try {
    if (keycloak.isTokenExpired()) {
      console.log("Token is expired. Renewing token...");
      try {
        await keycloak.updateToken(60);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(
          "Refresh Token Failed : " + JSON.stringify(error, null, 4)
        );
        window.location.reload();
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error checking/renewing token:", error);
  }
}
```